# How do I pass input fields from page 1 to hidden fields on page 2 and then display hidden fields from page 2 to page 3 in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, session, cookies

I need to pass the following information from page 1 to hidden files in page 2. Additional information is added on page 2 and all input fields have to be displayed on page 3?
Page 1 is below registration.html:

```
<form method="POST" action="interests.php" onsubmit="return checkForm(this);">
        <p>Use tab key to move from one input field to the next.</p>
        <label for="userName">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter your Username" /><div><span id='errorusername'></span></div>

        <label for="passWord1">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="pwd1" placeholder="Enter your Password" /><div><span id='errorpwd1'></span></div>

        <label for="passwordword2">Verify your Password:
        </label>
        <input type="password" name="pwd2" placeholder="Enter in your Password again" /><div><span id='errorpwd2'></span></div>

        <label for="firstName">First Name:
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="Enter your First Name" /><div><span id='errorfirstName'></span></div>

         <label for="lastName">Last Name:
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Enter your Last Name" /><div><span id='errorlastName'></span></div>

        <label for="email">Email:
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter your Email Address" /><div><span id='erroremail'></span></div>

        <label for="phone">Phone Number
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Enter your Phone Number" /><div><span id='errorphone'></span></div>



        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Next Step">

    </form>
```

Page 2 follows:

```
form method="POST" action="confirm.php" onsubmit="return checkForm(this);">

        <p><label>Interest:</label></p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="fund" value="fund"/><span>Fund Raising</span>
        <input type="checkbox" name="sponsor" value="sponsor" /><span>Sponsorship</span>
       <input type="checkbox" name="vol" value="vol" /><span>Volunteer</span><div></div>

        <p><label for="signUpNewsletter">Sign up for newsletter:
        </label></p>
        <input type="radio" name="signUpNewsletter" value="Yes"> Yes 
        <input type="radio" name="signUpNewsletter" value="No"> No

        <p><label for="desc">Comments:</label></p>
        <textarea name="desc" id="desc" rows="10" cols="30"></textarea>

        <p><label for="referred"> Referred by:</label></p>
        <input type="text" name="referred" />
       <?php
            if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
        {
            $username= $_POST["username"];
            $pwd1= $_POST["pwd1"];
        }
        ?>

        <input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo $_POST["username"]; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="pwd1" value="<?php echo $_POST["pwd1"]; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="pwd2" value="<?php $_POST["pwd2"]; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="firstName" value="<?php echo $_POST["firstName"]; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="lastName" value="<?php echo $_POST["lastName"]; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="phone" value="<?php echo $_POST["phone"]; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="fund" value="<?php echo $_POST["fund"]; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="sponsor" value="<?php echo $_POST["sponsor"]; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="vol" value="<?php echo $_POST["vol"]; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="sign" value="<?php echo $_POST["sign"]; ?>">


        <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Register">
    </form>
```

Page 3 needs to display the information inputted from page 1 as well as page 2:

```
<section id="pageFormContent">

    <p>You have successfully registered!</p>

    <?php

        if(isset($_POST["submit1"]))
       {
            $username= $_POST["username"];
            $pwd1= $_POST["pwd1"];
            $pwd2= $_POST["pwd2"];
            $firstName= $_POST["firstName"];
            $lastName= $_POST["lastName"];
            $email= $_POST["email"];
            $phone= $_POST["phone"];
            $fund= $_POST["fund"];
            $sponsor= $_POST["sponsor"];
            $vol= $_POST["vol"];
            $sign= $_POST["sign"];
            echo $username;
            echo $pwd1;
            echo $pwd2;
            echo $firstName;
            echo $lastName;
            echo $email;
            echo $phone;
            echo $fund;
            echo $sponsor;
            echo $vol;
            echo $sign;
         }




    ?>



</section>
```

When the submit button is pressed, the only thing that displays is "You have successfully registered!"
Can anyone tell me why the data is not displaying?

Comment: Changes were made and the code still does not work to display information on the third page. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In page 2 change the hidden values from `<?php echo $username; ?>` to `<?php echo $_POST['username']; ?>` and try to post it

```
<input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo $_POST['username']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="password" value="<?php echo $_POST['pwd1']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="passwordVerify" value="<?php $_POST['pwd2']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="firstName" value="<?php echo $_POST['firstName']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="lastName" value="<?php echo $_POST['lastName']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $_POST['email']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="phone" value="<?php echo $_POST['phone']; ?>">
```

Comment: I made the above changes and it still only displays "You have successfully registered!"

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your $_POST["username"] in the next line and the respecting fields in the rest instead of
">
The $username variable is not set at the time.

Comment: I made the changes and it still does not display the information correctly on the third page. Could it possibly be an error on the third page not retrieving the data?

Comment: Did your check if the hidden values are set on the 2nd page?

Comment: Also there is a "<" missing before the form on the 2nd page. Was it just a misselection for the post on SO or is it like this in your file?